# Ionic2 change Tabs selectedIndex property from a childpage

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm kind of a beginer in Angular2 and Ionic2. I am trying to build my own small app using Ionic2's Tabs component.

I want to be able to change the tab using a button in my childpage. I have tried using `NavController.setRoot()` and `NavController.push()` but none of them have the desired behaviour.

`setRoot(Homepage)` sets the correct view but doesn't change the selected tab in the tab menu.
`push(Homepage)` sets the correct view but the Tabs menu is not visible anymore.

I am a bit confused about how should I comnunicate with the TabsPage (the @Component that holds the tabs) from my single pages.

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem. pop(), push() with tabs just do not work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there should be an easier way to do this, but I did it this way:

Because in order to change the active tab you should do it from the Tabs Component, I used a **shared service** to handle the communication between *the pages inside the tab* and *the tab container (the component that holds the tabs)*. Even though you probably could do it with [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) I like the **shared service** approach because is easier to understand and also to mantain when the applications start growing.

So basically the `TabServices`only creates an `Observable` to allow the tabs container to subscribe to it, and also declares the `changeTabInContainerPage()` method that will be called from the tab pages.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular/index';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TabService { 

  private tabChangeObserver: any;
  public tabChange: any;

  constructor(private platform: Platform){
    this.tabChangeObserver = null;
    this.tabChange = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.tabChangeObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  public changeTabInContainerPage(index: number) {
    this.tabChangeObserver.next(index);
  }

}
```

Then, in each page (inside the tabs) we only add a button and bind that to a method that calls the service:

Page1.html

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <div padding style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>

    <button secondary (click)="changeTab()">Select next tab</button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Page1.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { TabService } from 'tabService.ts';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"page1.html"
})
export class Page1 {

  constructor(private tabService: TabService) { }

  public changeTab() {
    this.tabService.changeTabInContainerPage(1);
  }
}
```

And finally, in the tabs component, we only subscribe to the method in the service, and then we change the selected tab with `this.tabRef.select(index);`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Page1 } from './page1.ts';
import { Page2 } from './page2.ts';
import { TabService } from 'tabService.ts'; 


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  tab1Root: any = Page1;
  tab2Root: any = Page2;

  constructor(private tabService: TabService){
    this.tabService.tabChange.subscribe((index) => {
      this.tabRef.select(index);
    });
  }
}
```

Please notice that we're getting a reference to the `Tabs` instance by adding `#myTabs` in the `ion-tabs` element, and we get it from the component with `@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;`

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I'm a bit confused about how should I do that with events. I tried using  [this example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent) but here the TabsPage template doesn't contain the tab directive.