# Passing data from child tab to parent tab in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I know we can pass data to the child tab from parent tab by doing following as described [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/):

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" [rootParams]="chatParams" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chat"><ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Is there any way I can do the reverse stuff i.e passing the data from child tab to parent tab.

I have the following scenario:
1. I have "next" button on the the Tabs(parent) page.
2. When user selects the value on the child page then I need to navigate the user to next page based on the selected value when he clicks next.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405356/ionic2-change-tabs-selectedindex-property-from-a-childpage/38413101#38413101) could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have met your problem. you should use [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.7/api/util/Events/) in Ionic 2 for sending and responding to application level across your app. So you can send data from child tab to parent tab and update status for it.

Comment: How do you do the opposite though? Send data from parent (root) to child (pages).

Comment: @Mukus reference "https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/" . It has example for you. =))